# My script tags not working after page loaded on next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I tried many ways but i couldn't run.

external script

```
const sa = document.getElementById("clickk");

sa.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert('hello')
})
```

my button from component:

```
 <button id="clickk">Click</button>
```

my script tags (page/_document.js):

[image]